# When using keybindings a capital letter is assumed by Aquamacs

Tags: osx, aquamacs

I have an issue with Aquamacs. When press something like `C-c a t` (= org-todo-list in org-mode) the minibuffer shows an error message that there is no keybinding for `^C A`, despite `Shift` is neither pressed nor locked. I tried this with various other keybindings, yet to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact message you get when you do `C-h k C-c a`?

Comment: On pressing `C-h k` I am asked to `Describe key (or click or menu item):`, and when I then press `C-c a` the same error message appears: `^C A is undefined`.

Comment: I don't use Mac so couldn't help more other than asking you to verify if you see the same problem in an `emacs -Q` session. Launch `emacs -Q`, bind `C-c a` to `org-agenda` and then do `C-h k C-c a`.

Comment: Can you please paste in your question the **exact** and complete buffer contents when you do `C-h k C-c a`? You using `^C A` looks very strange to me. Emacs should be reporting `C-a` or `C-S-a` as far as I know.

Comment: Well, the buffer is empty: I opened a fresh new "Untitled" buffer and started `org-mode`. When I press `C-h`, the minibuffer shows `^C H` (that is with a capital `H`), I then told to enter a letter or `?` for a list of options in the minibuffer. If I press `C-c a` the same error message appears as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Well then it could be something in Aquamacs that's displaying `^C A` instead of `C-c a`.

Answer (score 1):

The key binding is not set-up by default, it is a just a recommendation from `org-mode`.  You need to add something like

```el
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
```

to your init file, or `Preferences.el` for Aquamacs.  In my init file I have

```el
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

Part of the reason for this is that `C-c` sequences are meant to be reserved for user defined short cuts.  Without these definitions you can always type for example `M-x org-agenda` to run the agenda command.

Comment: I am confused why he is emphasizing that emacs reports the binding as `^C A` with uppercase A. *It's also strange to read `^C A` instead of `C-S-a` or `C-a`. I don't think emacs would ever report `C-S-a` binding as `C-A`.*

Comment: @AndrewSwann: that would be quite annoying, considering the hundreds of keybindings explained in detail in the manual, which I even bought in print. Moreover, I am pretty sure I tried the agenda view some days before, and the keybinding worked at that time. I installed Aquamacs plain vanilla and didn't tinker with any of its configuration files.

Comment: @SingulaereEntitaet `C-c a` has to be bound by the user. Based on our discussion in the comments, implementing Andrew's solution should fix your problem. As per [**Activation - Org Manual**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Activation.html#Activation), `C-c a` is a *suggested* binding; user can bind as suggested if they wish. Emacs cannot ship with pre-bound `C-c SINGLE-LETTER` bindings.

Comment: I stand corrected, @kaushalmodi.